# How to resolve  the issue "No source available for "msvcrt!fgets() " "

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class Chkinval
        {
         char  *inval;
         char *inarray;
         public:
         void inPutProcessor();

        };


void Chkinval::inPutProcessor()
{
     cout << "Input" ;
     fgets(inval,1000,stdin);
     int tmp = atoi(inval);

     for(int lpcnt=0;lpcnt< tmp;lpcnt++)
     {
           fgets(inarray,1000,stdin);
     }
     for(int lpcnt=0;lpcnt< tmp;lpcnt++)
     {
         cout << "The array elements" << inarray[lpcnt];
     }
    }

int main()
{

    Chkinval tmp1 ;
    tmp1.inPutProcessor();

    return 0;
    }
```

Issue :

The program compiles fine but no result in the console

In the debug mode

i am getting the error message "No source available for "msvcrt!fgets() ""

Is it a operating system issue or do i need to install any library ?

Comment: It's because it's crashing (probably here `fgets(inval,1000,stdin);`) because you're reading 1000 bytes to some random address read from an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: how to initialize the pointer? using new or malloc ?

Comment: That would be one way (I'd recommend using `std::string` and/or `std::vector` instead). Your code has other problems as well.

Comment: i am new to c++ so if you can point out the problems it will be great help i do have  question regarding the initializing of char pointer inside a member function  and in main function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code as it is now is that neither `inval` nor `inarray` are initialized and you're thus reading up to 1000 bytes into some arbitrary memory location.

```
 for(int lpcnt=0;lpcnt< tmp;lpcnt++)
 {
       fgets(inarray,1000,stdin);
 }
```

Is probably also not what you want (even if `inarray` was initialized) since it'll overwrite the contents on each iteration.

```
 fgets(inval,1000,stdin);
 int tmp = atoi(inval);
```

Is not wrong per se, but you're probably better off using `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &tmp)` (if you were coding C, read on).

A lot of these problems stem from the fact that your code is very C-like. There is no reason (unless it's for homework) to manage that many allocations on your own in C++. Here is a small example that shows a more C++-way of doing some of the things:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Number of elements to read? " << std::flush;

    // How many lines should we read?
    int count;
    if (!(std::cin >> count) || count <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Invalid element count" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }


    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    // Read until EOF (to get newline from above reading)
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << "Error reading line" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read lines one at a time adding them to the 'lines' vector
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
            std::cout << "Error reading line" << std::endl;
            return 1;    
        }
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    // Echo the lines back
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator line_iterator = lines.begin(); line_iterator != lines.end(); ++line_iterator) {
        std::cout << *line_iterator << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```